# Jquery sortable function is not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, jquery-ui

Here is my code

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#admin-page-wrapper ul').sortable({cursor: 'move'});

});
```

Here is my order of jquery which are enqued

```
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
```

And here is my plugin code

```
<div id="admin-page-wrapper">
        <h2>Published Pages</h2>
        <?php 
            $pages = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'page','post_status'=>'publish','posts_per_page'=>'-1','order'=>'ASC'));
        ?>
            <ul id="dashboard-page">
          <?php  if($pages -> have_posts()){
                while($pages -> have_posts()){
                    $pages->the_post(); ?>
                    <li class="dashboard-item"><?php echo the_title(); ?></li>
                <?php }
            } ?>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what error do you see in your console?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: TypeError: jQuery(...).sortable is not a function
jQuery('#admin-page-wrapper ul').sortable({cursor: 'move'});

Comment: How is your jQuery and jQueryUI loaded into page? Original jQuery always needs to be loaded first and don't forget to also load jQueryUI.

Comment: @AWA  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');

Comment: @AWA first i am adding jquery and then jquery-ui-core and when i do ctrl+u i do not find jquery.js anywhere across the page however jquery-ui-core exist there. is there another way to add jquery.js.

Comment: Hmm, it's very hard to tell. Maybe you could try adding jQuery with other parameters like `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', null, null, false );`

Comment: @AWA have tried in this wp_enqueue_script('jquery',null,null,false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core',null,null,false); way also but problem still persist.

Comment: Add 3rd script & add it as last one: `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable');`

Comment: @AWA you are genius man!! you made it workable. Thanks a ton. Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add 3rd script & add it as last one:

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable');
```

You can find a list of all WordPress built in scripts at this page:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script